# The useage of PPPoED_Tags in scapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy, packet, pppoe

I want to create a PPPOE packet , now i have a problem about the useage of  PPPoED_Tags.
You can see as follows:
[image: PPPoE Tags goes here]

The tips is as follows, but i just can not understand it
[image: tips of PPPoE Tags]

So I want to know how to transfer parameters.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Fortunately,I solved it by mistake